# Build satand alone application using netbeans modules

Tags: java, netbeans

Im trying to build a text editor and I would like to incorporate modules from netbeans, like Diff module, etc. 
I've found information about how to build an component in order to execute it as a netbean module, but im trying to use this component as a stand alone application. 
So my question is: Is it possible to do this?
Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Your best starting point will be the documentation on the old NetBeans page: https://netbeans.org/kb/trails/platform.html

The information there was not transitioned to the new site yet, but that does *not* mean that it's outdated or useless.